# JavaScript error while trying to hide table rows

Tags: javascript, css, xhtml

I am trying to display rows depending upon users choice. Suppose (s)he wants only 3 rows, then the fourth and fifth row will hide. Please find below the part of html and javascript.

HTML

```
<table>
  <tr id="sRow1">
    <td>1a</td>
    <td>1b</td>
  </tr>
  <tr id="sRow2">
    <td>2a</td>
    <td>2b</td>
  </tr>
  <tr id="sRow3">
    <td>3a</td>
    <td>3b</td>
  </tr>
  <tr id="sRow4">
    <td>4a</td>
    <td>4b</td>
  </tr>
  <tr id="sRow5">
    <td>5a</td>
    <td>5b</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

JavaScript

```
// b gets value from xml file        
    while (b <= 5)
    {
        var rowName = "sRow" + b;
        alert(rowName);
        try {
            document.getElementById(rowName).style.display = "none";
        }
        catch (err)
        {
            alert(err.description)
        }
        b++;
    }
```

I am getting Object required error at document.getElementById(rowName).style.display = "none";. Can you please help.

Comment: I don't see why you would need try-catch here. Are you sure `document.getElementById(rowName)` actually finds element? If it doesn't, it should return `null` and further property access - i.e. `.style.display` - should result in an error. To prevent this, simply check for element existence before trying to set its style.

Comment: Works for me for eg. `b=4`. Maybe `b` is not what you expected? What is the rowName you get alerted just before the error?

Comment: Another strange observation, if I change the id names from sRow to sib, it works. Is sRow a keyword of some sorts. Regards

Comment: No, but there could be some other use of ‘sRow’ elsewhere in your page? What you've posted is OK so the error must be elsewhere. URL?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're missing the interesting bit (where `b` comes from), so I'm gonna just guess: *sometimes* `b` isn't actually a number between 1 and 5 inclusive. Maybe it's a string that doesn't format cleanly to a single-digit numeral 1-5, or maybe it's something else entirely... Let's make your code a bit safer, just in case I'm right:

```
// b gets value from xml file

// ensure b is a number - will fail comparison if NaN
b = new Number(b);
while (b <= 5)
{
  var rowName = "sRow" + b;
  var row = document.getElementById(rowName);
  if ( row ) // verify element was found before trying to modify it!
    row.style.display = "none";
  b++;
}
```

Note that I've removed the `try {} catch` - you're better off just testing the return value of `getElementById()`, since that won't interfere with debugging should you wish to use a debugger later on...

Comment: Thanks. alerts(rowName) shows the correct id. So the value of b is not the problem. Regards

Comment: @kobra: are you *sure*? It's notoriously hard to see spaces at the end of a string displayed in an `alert()` dialog...

Comment: @Vagabond - putting the declaration inside the try {} solved the problem, which makes it a scope issue.

Comment: @karim79: it's not scope. Scope in JavaScript does not work that way. See my comment on your answer...

Comment: Thanks for bring that to notice. I tried alert(rowName+"gs") to check your point. Still getting the correct alert. Regards

Answer (score 1):

In my experience, you'll get inconsistent results across different browsers trying to make table rows invisible by modifying style attributes. A safer thing to do is to actually remove and insert the rows from the table using the [insertRow()](http://www.w3schools.com/HTMLDOM/met_table_insertrow.asp) and [deleteRow()](http://www.w3schools.com/HTMLDOM/met_table_deleterow.asp) dom methods on the table object. This is properly supported across all major browsers you're likely to encounter.

Comment: Thanks. Can you point to some example? I find this way interesting. Regards.

Comment: Sure. There are code examples in the method name links in my answer. See above. :)

Comment: Thanks. Sorry for overlooking. Regards

Comment: There shouldn't be any problems with setting ‘display: none’ on a row; I've never had any difficulty on any browser. However setting it back to ‘display: table-row’ is not so easy because of a bug in IE, which requires ‘display: block’ instead. I usually find it easiest to add/remove a ‘hidden’ class to the row, and then ‘.hidden { display: none; }’ from CSS.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are missing the runat attribute with the row id, as you have mentioned the id of the row but didn't mentioned the runat attribute, if you don't mentioned runat attribute then that error comes.

Comment: Its a simple html webpage with javascript. So the question of runat server or client does not arise. Regards